# The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML

Tags: xml, email, iis, office365

We are trying to setup a scenario where out application running on windows server 2019 IIS goes and login with the following email address username and password specified and automatically send an mail back to the client from office 365.

In simple terms the app must open web URL login with credentials given and send mail.

I went through a lot of the forms already and tried to change the URL quick a few times since some of the forms aren't consisted what to actually use here.

So what needs to happen application needs to contact Office 365 on URL (https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx) as per previous forms stated but then we get the following error:

> "The error message you're encountering, "(401) Unauthorized"

We have given permission on the noreply/order email address on 365 and double checked username and password but error message still persists we also made sure 2 factor auth is off on 365 admin center for this mail box to sent out and delegations are correct.. We also used https://autodiscover.outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx since in  the admin portal of 365 it seems that everything is set to autodiscover but with no success.

We then changed the URL to "https://outlook.office.com/mail/ourdomain.co.za/EWS/Exchange.asmx" as per other forms, you get the office 365 login page which seems to be the correct URL but now we are getting this error:

> "The response received from the service didn't contain valid XML"

We are not running an hybrid solution and only want to use the application to send via office 365 we do not have an on site exchange server. Firewalls rules were also checked and cant seem to find anything blocking this requests.

Also I am not to sure if there is anything I need to do on our windows server IIS side the only thing I tried there was to add and allow the URL under sites in IIS request filtering which also did not make any difference.

Please see current code of application. Areas in **** we have the actual details filled in.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);

            //Set your Exchange server URL and credentials.
            try
            {
                // Set the correct URL for Office 365.
                service.Url = new  Uri("https://outlook.office.com/mail/ourdomain.co.za/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("WebService Uri: " + ex.Message);
            }


            try
            {
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("****user@ourdomain.co.za****",     "****userpassword****");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Credentials: " + ex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
                email.Subject = "Your Visits for today";
                email.Body = new MessageBody("The email is working");
                email.ToRecipients.Add("****Recipients@ourdomain.co.za****");
                email.Send();

                return Ok("Email sent");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Message Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Please any help or assistance will help greatly since we are currently at this point we do not know what to check further.

Comment: Most server (Office 365) has moved from Windows Credentials to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 is supported by Windows, MAC, and Linux.   OAUTH2 you send two requests.  First gets a token/cookie from server and second you perform the query.  Do a google search for "office 365 authentication".

Comment: Enable logging for your ExchangeService to get more detailed information about the requests and responses. This can help identify any specific issues with the communication. Add the following lines before making the service call:

`service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;`
Then, check the trace logs for more information.